# changing default value of ion-checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ion-checkbox

I have created a form which uses ion-checkboxes in angular, which when ticked submits "true" to the database, how do I submit the value of the box to the database, so for example in my list is Junior Groups, so I would like "Junior Groups" to appear in the database and not true. The form also sends an email so the recipient needs to know what the enquiry is interested in.

Code so far is:

html form:

```
<form [formGroup]="coachingform">
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
<ion-col>
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label position="start">First Name</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" formControlName="firstname"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label position="start">Last Name</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" formControlName="surname"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label position="start">Email</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label position="start">Contact Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="tel" formControlName="telnumber"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="start">What city are you based in?</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" formControlName="location"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-list>
  <ion-label>What are you interested in?</ion-label>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of form">
    <ion-label>{{entry.val}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="start" formControlName="interestedin"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

then in the .ts file have the list as such:

```
export class CoachingenquiryPage implements OnInit {
coachingform: FormGroup
public form = [
{ val: 'Junior Groups', isChecked: true },
{ val: 'Adult Groups', isChecked: true },
{ val: 'Individual Lessons', isChecked: true },
{ val: 'Holiday Camps', isChecked: true },
];
```

any help would be hugely appreciated. many thanks

the updated .ts code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray }    
from '@angular/forms'
import { HttpClient, } from '@angular/common/http';
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-coachingenquiry',
templateUrl: './coachingenquiry.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./coachingenquiry.page.scss'],
})
export class CoachingenquiryPage implements OnInit {
coachingform: FormGroup
public options= [
{ val: 'Junior Groups', isChecked: true },
{ val: 'Adult Groups', isChecked: true },
{ val: 'Individual Lessons', isChecked: true },
{ val: 'Holiday Camps', isChecked: true },
];

constructor(private http: HttpClient, public fb: FormBuilder, private   
router: Router) { 
this.coachingform = this.fb.group({
  firstname: [''],
  surname: [''],
  email: [''],
  telnumber: [''],
  location: [''],
  interestedTopics: this.fb.array([]),

})
const control = this.coachingform.get("interestedTopics") as  
FormArray;
this.options.forEach(f => {
  const group = this.fb.group({
    interestedin: [f.isChecked]
  });
  control.push(group);
});
}

ngOnInit() {
this.coachingform = new FormGroup({
  firstname: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required]
  }),
  surname: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required]
  }),
  email: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]
  }),
  telnumber: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[- +()0-9]  
 {11,}')]
  }),
  location: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required]
  }),
  interestedin: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required]
  }),
  })
}
onSubmitForm () {
var formData: any = new FormData();
formData.append("firstname",   
this.coachingform.get('firstname').value);
formData.append("surname", this.coachingform.get('surname').value);
formData.append("email", this.coachingform.get('email').value);
formData.append("telnumber", 
this.coachingform.get('telnumber').value);
formData.append("location", this.coachingform.get('location').value);
formData.append("interestedin",   
this.coachingform.get('interestedin').value);
this.http.post('https://www.parktennis.org/app/services/app-    
coachingenquiry.php', formData, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(() 
=> {
this.coachingform.reset();
this.router.navigate(['/','landing']);
  });

}
}
```

Comment: Check out my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-checkbox slot="start" formControlName="interestedin"></ion-checkbox>
```

This won't work. Because I think `interestedin` is just a `FormControl` of your `coachingform` FormGroup.

You need to use `FormArray` for handling arrays.

**First**, Add an 'FormArray' in your `coachingform` FormGroup like:

```
this.coachingform = this.builder.group({
    firstname: [null],
    surname: [null],
    ...
    interestedTopics: this.builder.array([])
});
```

**Then**, add new controls into the array for all of your options.

```
const control = this.coachingform.get("interestedTopics") as FormArray;
control.clear();
this.options.forEach(f => {
    const group = this.builder.group({
    interestedin: [f.isChecked],
    value: [f.val]
});
control.push(group);
```

**Note:** For convenience, I've renamed your checkbox options from `form` to `options`.

**And finally**, your `ion-list` will be:

```
<ion-list formArrayName="interestedTopics">
    <ion-label>What are you interested in?</ion-label>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of options; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <ion-label>{{entry.val}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox slot="start" formControlName="interestedin"></ion-checkbox>
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-qy2qss?file=src/app/app.component.html).

**Result:**

[image]

**Edit:**

Remove the `form` related code from your `constructor`.

Change your `ngOnInit()` hook as:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.coachingform = new FormGroup({
      firstname: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: "blur",
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      surname: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: "blur",
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      email: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: "blur",
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]
      }),
      telnumber: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: "blur",
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[- +()0-9]{11,}")]
      }),
      location: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: "blur",
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      interestedTopics: this.builder.array([])
    });
    const control = this.coachingform.get("interestedTopics") as FormArray;
    control.clear();
    this.options.forEach(f => {
      const group = this.builder.group({
        interestedin: [f.isChecked]
      });
      control.push(group);
    });
  }
```

To get selection options:

```
const controlValue = this.coachingform.get("interestedTopics").value;
const selectedOptions = controlValue
    .filter(f => f.interestedin)
    .map(m => m.value);
```

Comment: many thanks Zunayed, really appreciate the help. I am getting the following error in the console log Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'control.clear' when I use the code above, should I be including something else?

Comment: Remove `control.clear();`. It won't be an issue for you.

Comment: thanks, i tried that but got another error Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'control.push'

Comment: Did you miss this line `interestedTopics: this.builder.array([])` inside your `formGroup` initialization?

Comment: yes sorry had it as interestedin and not interestedTopics! Have changed it and another error, must be nearly there: now getting Error: Cannot find control with path: 'interestedTopics -> 0'

Comment: it works! many thanks, now sends an array to the database. However the array is Interested In: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], how do I insert the values "Junior Groups", "Adult Groups" etc? thanks for the help!

Comment: Check the demo link again. I've added a button for test purposes. Check console log to see the value.

Comment: many thanks Zunayed for help, got it all to work now.